# Split a string with letters, numbers, and punctuation

Tags: java, regex

How do I split a string such as

```
wo.rd55hello?35.7e+2CAPS!-78.00E-7
```

to

```
wo.rd 55 hello? 35.7e+2 CAPS! -78.00E-7
```

Comment: Probably you have to use `Regular expressions`

Comment: Yea, I'm using regular expressions. I'm stuck separating the numbers that have e, E, and .

Comment: Add some code what you tried

Comment: so what is the rule here? should we guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new approach since Java's `Regex.Split()` doesn't seem to keep the delimiters in the result, even if they are enclosed in a capturing group:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "[+-]?           # Match a number, starting with an optional sign,\n" +
    "\\d+            # a mandatory integer part,\n" +
    "(?:\\.\\d+)?    # optionally followed by a decimal part\n" +
    "(?:e[+-]?\\d+)? # and/or an exponential part.\n" +
    "|               # OR\n" +
    "(?:             # Match...\n" +
    " (?![+-]?\\d)   # (unless it's the beginning of a number)\n" +
    " .              # any character\n" +
    ")*              # any number of times.", 
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

Note that this regex doesn't match "abbreviated" decimal numbers like `1.` or `.1` correctly - it assumes that a decimal number always as an integer part and a decimal part. If those cases need to be included, the regex will need to be augmented.

Comment: Thanks. This is splitting by the numbers but I'd like the numbers to be included too. Also, what is (?ix)

Comment: Ah, so Java behaves unlike other regex engines that include the delimiter in the result list if it's enclosed in a capturing group...in that case you need a different approach. Hang on a minute. (by the way, I commented the regex to explan what `(?ix)` means - case-insensitive matching and verbose (comments) mode)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this website to develop your regex expression: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it has a library of tokens and a description. It also has realtime highlight. You can see the results (that you wish). Its really easy to use and I think there is a desktop version.